# How do I accomplish viewing a 2D game board in 3D space?

Tags: 2d, 3d, camera, unreal-5

So I'm making a 2D board game in 3D space and I don't want to use paper2D because I'm not really using sprites.

What I want is to be able to make a grid of cubes positioned such that I can have a camera facing the grid and it will only show the one face of all the cubes. The idea is that to the player it will just look like a 2D board.

The problem I'm having is, If I make a Cube and move it up/down/left/right, the Camera sees more than just one face despite it being manually positioned to be looking head on at the cube.

[image: Sees other angles of cube]

So then I remembered that I probably want an orthographic view, so I set the camera to that and unfortunately its just wireframe.

[image: wireframe]

**So my question is, how do I accomplish this? Does UE5 not support this kind of thing at all?**

Answer (score 1):

This may be the same as other reported [errors with UE5 ortho camera preview](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/bug-orthographic-camera-appears-to-be-broken-in-ue-5-0/524692):

> ...the Orthographic camera seems to be only outputting wireframes in preview mode…I did a verify and a full reinstall and this issue is still here. Further I initiated a camera shake when damage is taken which for SOME reason outputs flashing lights as opposed to JUST a camera shake.
>
> When I switch the camera to perspective and apply damage the Camera shake works as normal.

Some similar problems were [reported and verified in UE4](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/orthographic-camera-render-broken-4-0-2/280893), but have yet to be resolved. It was initially reported in
April 2014 and reportedly still broken in August 2020.

It's possible someone else will know of & post a workaround; just because I didn't happen to find one doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Theoretically, if the final rendering is fine, you could just put up with it in preview mode & use intermittent release quality builds to judge the visuals. Up voting &/or posting the issue on the forum might help signal to the developers that this is something you would like them to prioritize.

Comment: Alternatively, I could be completely off base - you might have a different problem entirely with a workable solution. I posted this because based on what I can tell, it seems very similar to the issues you've described in your question.